# print all loops once/together in python

Tags: python, loops, addition

if I have a simple for loop like:

```
for i in range(10):
   total = 0
   total = total + i
   print(total)
```

How can I print the loops once/together like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Instead of every loop by itself:

```
1
2
3 etc
```

Comment: Why are you resetting `total` to `0`, adding `i` to it and printing it? Why not just `print(i, end="")`?

Comment: I just tried to make a simple loop to ask this question. 
I didn't know about using end

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(10):
   total = 0
   total = total + i
   print(total,end=" ")
```

The ability of `print` function, end of the each line changing from `\n` to `" "`